# Integral Form of Conservation or Energy and Momentum in General Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm solving the assignments of the General Relativity course provided by [MIT Open Courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-962-general-relativity-spring-2020/resources/mit8_962s20_pset02/), and in question 4 of the problem set 2 I'm asked to prove that

$$\partial_0\int{T^{0\alpha}}\mathrm{d}^3x = 0$$

By using

$$\partial_{\nu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$$.

However, I think this may be wrong because if I expand the last expression on $\nu$ I get

$$\partial_{0}T^{0\alpha} + \partial_{j}T^{j\alpha} = 0 \implies \partial_{0}\int{T^{0\alpha}}\mathrm{d}^3x + \partial_{j}\int{T^{j\alpha}}\mathrm{d}^3x = 0$$.

So, for the hypothesis to be true, I should have

$$\partial_{j}\int{T^{j\alpha}}\mathrm{d}^3x = 0$$.

Which I don't see why would be the case...

---

I forgot to mention that the system is bounded by a volume $\mathcal{V}$, so

$$\int \partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu} \mathrm{d}^3x = \int_{\mathcal{V}}\partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu} \mathrm{d}^3x = \int_{\partial \mathcal{V}} T^{\mu\nu}\mathrm{d}\Sigma$$

Comment: The integral is over the entire plane $t=$ constant, so it is translation invariant and does not depend on $x^j$.

Comment: What integral are you referring to? All of them don't depend on time and a change of spatial coordinates shouldn't change their value also, but that doesn't mean that their time derivative is zero.

Comment: I will spell out the details in an answer.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

We  assume that $T^{\mu\nu}(t, {\bf x})$  vanishes at large spatial distance ${\bf x}$ .

You want
$$
\partial_t \int_{{\mathbb R}^3} T^{tj}(t, {\bf x})d^3x.
$$
As $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$, this is  equal to
$$
 \int_{{\mathbb R}^3} \partial_tT^{tj}(t, {\bf x})= -\int_{{\mathbb R}^3} \partial_a T^{aj}(t, {\bf x}). 
$$
The sum on $a$ is over the spacial indices $1,2,3$.
By the divergence theorem, the second integral  is a  surface integral at large distance where $T^{\mu\nu}$ vanishes, and so it is zero.

Note that the while the integrand $T^{aj}(t, {\bf x})$ depends on $x$, its  integral
$$
\int_{{\mathbb R}^3}  T^{aj}(t, {\bf x})d^3x 
$$
does not depend on ${\bf x}$ as it has been integrated over. Thus it is *not true* in general that
$$
-\frac{\partial}{
\partial x^a} \int_{{\mathbb R}^3}  T^{aj}(t, {\bf x})d^3x = -\int_{{\mathbb R}^3}  \frac{\partial}{
\partial x^a}T^{aj}(t, {\bf x})d^3x.
$$

Comment: Oh right, I took the spatial derivative out of the integral carelessly. But on the second line of equation of your answer, wouldn't the surface integral have to encompass all the "mass" of $T$ even at infinity? I'm thinking of a parallel with Gauss' law of electrodynamics, where the total charge of a distribution completely encapsulated by a surface wouldn't change even if as surface scales to infinity.

Comment: Nope. The surface integral is $\int_D T^{aj}n^a d|S|$ which is zero because $T^{aj}$ is zero on $D$ which is at large distance. Gauss' Law has a surface contribution becase $\nabla\cdot {\bf D}=\rho$ is not everywhere zero when  $\rho$ is not ---  but $\partial_aT^{aj} $ is zero everywhere.

Comment: Ok, but $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\partial_{j}T^{j\nu}\mathrm{d}^3x = \int_{\mathcal{V}}\partial_{j}T^{j\nu}\mathrm{d}^3x + \int_{\mathbb{R}^3-\mathcal{V}}\partial_{j}T^{j\nu}\mathrm{d}^3x$. I agree that the $\mathbb{R}^3 - \mathcal{V}$ contribution is zero due to $T$ being zero on that region, but if the LHS of the equation is zero, the so must be $\int_{\mathcal{V}}\partial_{j}T^{j\nu}\mathrm{d}^3x$, which doesn't look true to me.

Comment: What does your notation ${\mathbb R}^3-{\mathcal V}$ mean? My $D$ is a two sphere are large distance--- effectively the "boundary" of  ${\mathbb R}^3$. I am using Stokes $\int_{\Omega} \nabla\cdot{\bf  V} d^3x= \int_{\partial \Omega} {\bf V}\cdot {\bf n}d|S|$.

Comment: By $\mathbb{R}^3 - \mathcal{V}$ I mean the region of space where there's no mass distribution. That is, $\mathcal{V}$ is where $T$ isn't zero, and its boundary would be denoted by $\partial \mathcal{V}$.